# Antd - How to change Select's initialValue based on sibling's getFieldValue in a Form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

In my form, there are 2 children per row in a list: Input and Select

In my input, if I type a set of a string that, when passed into regex, returns either a phone number, url or email, I want the Select component to automatically pre-select this field.

I am watching the Input's `getFieldValue` for what `type` I should select from the Select component.

The problem I am seeing is that `initialValue` for Select is only set on render (kinda makes sense based on it's name). I can't however change it afterwards and I don't know how I can programmatically call Select's `onChange` handler from the Input's `getFieldValue`.

Is this possible?

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/complex-dynamic-form-item-antd-5-7-2-forked-f3dpm5?file=/demo.tsx:1780-1793)

```
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Button, Form, Input, Select, Space } from "antd";

const { Option } = Select;

const options = [
  { label: "Work", value: "work" },
  { label: "Home", value: "home" },
  { label: "Mobile", value: "mobile" },
  { label: "URL", value: "url" },
  { label: "Email", value: "email" }
];

const validateCurrentInputValueType = (value: string) => {
  const isOnlyDigitsRegex = /^\d+$/;
  const isURLRegex = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+[^\s]*$/;
  const isEmailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;

  if (isOnlyDigitsRegex.test(value)) return "mobile";
  if (isURLRegex.test(value)) return "url";
  if (isEmailRegex.test(value)) return "email";

  // return "mobile";
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const onFinish = (values: any) => {
    console.log("Received values of form:", values);
  };

  const handleChange = () => {
    const vals = form.getFieldsValue();
    console.log("vals", vals);
  };

  return (
    <Form form={form} name="info-form" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="info">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
          <>
            {fields.map(({ key, name, fieldKey, ...restField }) => (
              <Space key={key} align="baseline">
                <Form.Item
                  label="Details"
                  {...restField}
                  name={[name, "info_input"]}
                  fieldKey={[fieldKey, "info_input"]}
                >
                  <Input />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item shouldUpdate style={{ marginLeft: 8, width: 100 }}>
                  {({ getFieldValue }) => {
                    const currentInputValue = getFieldValue([
                      "info",
                      name,
                      "info_input"
                    ]);

                    console.log("currentInputValue", currentInputValue);
                    const type = validateCurrentInputValueType(
                      currentInputValue
                    );
                    console.log("type", type);

                    return (
                      <Form.Item
                        name={[name, "info_select"]}
                        fieldKey={[fieldKey, "info_select"]}
                      >
                        <Select onChange={handleChange}>
                          {options.map((option) => (
                            <Option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                              {option.label}
                            </Option>
                          ))}
                        </Select>
                      </Form.Item>
                    );
                  }}
                </Form.Item>

                <MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => remove(name)} />
              </Space>
            ))}

            <Form.Item>
              <Button
                type="dashed"
                onClick={() => add()}
                block
                icon={<PlusOutlined />}
              >
                Add field
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </>
        )}
      </Form.List>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can validate the value in input `onChange` function and then set the value of select component. If `validateCurrentInputValueType` function does not return any value, it'll not set any value for select field.

Here's the complete code.

```
import React from "react";
import "./index.css";
import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Button, Form, Input, Select, Space } from "antd";

const options = [
  { label: "Work", value: "work" },
  { label: "Home", value: "home" },
  { label: "Mobile", value: "mobile" },
  { label: "URL", value: "url" },
  { label: "Email", value: "email" }
];

const validateCurrentInputValueType = (value: string) => {
  const isOnlyDigitsRegex = /^\d+$/;
  const isURLRegex = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)+[^\s]*$/;
  const isEmailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$/;

  if (isOnlyDigitsRegex.test(value)) return "mobile";
  if (isURLRegex.test(value)) return "url";
  if (isEmailRegex.test(value)) return "email";

  // return "mobile";
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const onFinish = (values: any) => {
    console.log("Received values of form:", values);
  };

  return (
    <Form
      form={form}
      name="infoForm"
      onFinish={onFinish}
      autoComplete="off"
      onValuesChange={(changedValues, values) => {
        console.log(changedValues, values);
      }}
    >
      <Form.List name="info">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => (
          <>
            {fields.map(({ key, name, ...restField }) => (
              <Space key={key} align="baseline">
                <Form.Item
                  label="Details"
                  {...restField}
                  name={[name, "info_input"]}
                >
                  <Input
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      const type = validateCurrentInputValueType(
                        e.target.value
                      );
                      if (type) {
                        form.setFieldValue(["info", name, "info_select"], type);
                      }
                    }}
                  />
                </Form.Item>
                <Form.Item name={[name, "info_select"]}>
                  <Select options={options} placeholder="Select Value" />
                </Form.Item>
                <MinusCircleOutlined onClick={() => remove(name)} />
              </Space>
            ))}

            <Form.Item>
              <Button
                type="dashed"
                onClick={() => add()}
                block
                icon={<PlusOutlined />}
              >
                Add field
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </>
        )}
      </Form.List>
      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;
```